# How to handle optional date parameters?

Tags: javascript, datetime

When creating a function to be reusable throughout the project I came across something strange. After looking at this function it looks very much like it could be refactored.

The function should only return the short month and day, in that order. If it receives a parameter, it will be a Firestore Timestamp with the following format:

```json
{
   "seconds":1667420699,
   "nanoseconds":394000000
}
```

If it does not receive a parameter, it must return today's month and day. So I did this:

```js
function shortMonthDay(timestamp = undefined) {
  let date

  if (timestamp) {
    date = new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000)
  } else {
    date = new Date()
  }

  return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric'
  }) // Nov 2
}
```

The function works as it should, it doesn't return any errors. But I wonder if it could be improved and how.

Comment: Is the number of nanoseconds in the current second somehow relevant to what day it is?

Comment: I hadn't tested it without the nanoseconds before, but it actually doesn't seem to make that much of a difference. But it is a fact that JSON will come with nanoseconds.

Comment: @radarbob why would it matter? He's not returning the Date object... He just wants the string and uses Date internally to build it. There's no comparison of dates.

Comment: ARNON I wanted to say you can omit nanoseconds from your calculation, even if it's coming from Api, it is irrelevant for this method.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for it. About refactoring the function: would you do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Minor points

- Default parameters eg `shortMonthDay(timestamp = undefined)` are only assigned to arguments that are undefined or contain `undefined`. To assign the default `undefined` will do nothing and is just code noise.
- The timestamp object is not vetted. If it contains seconds, it may not have nanoseconds (and visa versa), or either or both may not hold a number. You need to ensure that you do not pass NaN to the `Date` constructor when parsing the `timestamp`

### Function roles

`shortMonthDay` would be better as two functions.

1. `timestampToDate` to convert a `timestamp` if given to a date.
2. `formatDate` to format the date object, which you can curry with the locale format. Thus you don't need to touch the `timestampToDate` to change the output format

### Rewrite

We can rewrite the function as follows

```js
const formatDate = (loc = "en-US", format = {month: "short", day: "numeric"}) => 
  date => date.toLocaleDateString(loc, format);
const timestampToDate = (timestamp = {}) => new Date(
  (isNaN(timestamp.seconds) ? Date.now() : Number(timestamp.seconds) * 1000) +
  (isNaN(timestamp.nanoseconds) ? 0 : timestamp.nanoseconds * 1e-6)
);    
const toMonthDay = formatDate();

// basic tests
const timestamps = [undefined,   // current local date
  {seconds: 1670263910, nanoseconds: 394000000}, // ~ Dec 6 GMT+0800 for rest
  {seconds: 1670263910, nanoseconds: "blah"},
  {seconds: 1670263910},
  {seconds: "foo", nanoseconds: 1667420699000 + 394}
].forEach(timestamp => console.log(toMonthDay(timestampToDate(timestamp))));
```

**Note** As a habit I avoid divides as generally divides are slower than multiplies. Its just a habit, in this case the difference between `* 1e-6` and `/ 1e6` is inconsequential.

**Note** In `timestampToDate` the names are a little noisy and because the variable timestamp is being used so often one could also write it as

```
const timestampToDate = (stamp = {}) => new Date(
    (isNaN(stamp.seconds) ? Date.now() : Number(stamp.seconds) * 1000) +
    (isNaN(stamp.nanoseconds) ? 0 : stamp.nanoseconds * 1e-6)
  );
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It is really complete e I learned with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the discussion from the comment if nanoseconds matter default value can be passed with `||` if `timestamp` don't have any of the property.

Can be demonstrated as

```js
function shortMonthDay(timestamp) {
    let date = new Date(timestamp?.seconds * 1000 || Date.now() + (timestamp?.nanoseconds || 0) / 1000000);
    return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric'
    })
}

const timestamp = {
    "seconds": 1667420699,
    "nanoseconds": 394000000
};

console.log(`with timestamp ${shortMonthDay(timestamp)}`);
console.log(`without timestamp ${shortMonthDay()}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Without the `timestamp` parameter it compromises nanoseconds to 0 and seconds to the current timestamp.**

---

#### Performance

with old snippet

```js
function shortMonthDay(timestamp = undefined) {
  let date

  if (timestamp) {
    date = new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000)
  } else {
    date = new Date()
  }

  return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric'
  }) // Nov 2
}

const timestamp = {
    "seconds": 1667420699,
    "nanoseconds": 394000000
};

let res = [];
for(let i = 0; i< 10; i++){
  let start = window.performance.now();
  shortMonthDay(timestamp);
  res.push(window.performance.now() - start);
}
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With the altered snippet

```js
function shortMonthDay(timestamp) {
    let date = new Date(timestamp?.seconds * 1000 || Date.now() + (timestamp?.nanoseconds || 0) / 1000000);
    return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric'
    })
}

const timestamp = {
    "seconds": 1667420699,
    "nanoseconds": 394000000
};

let res = [];
for(let i = 0; i< 10; i++){
  let start = window.performance.now();
shortMonthDay(timestamp);
res.push(window.performance.now() - start);
}
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solution is valid, but when it doesn't receive any parameters, I look at this syntax `new Date(Date.now() + 0)` and it looks different to me. I didn't even know this would work until I tested it 1 minute ago. lol

Comment: @ARNON Even many professionals wouldn't be sure whether that's valid. In first place, make your code understandable at a glance. Only when you get significant performance gain, you should sacrifice readability. But the performance gain here is miniscule if not nonexistent and the provided benchmark is not reliable.